# Python ML - How to best rescue python ml value array

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I created a model with sklearn for classification. When I call the function `y_pred2 = clf.predict (features2)` it returns a list with all the ids of my prediction

```
y_pred2 = clf.predict(features2)
```

Print Array

```
array([**5**, 5, 5, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1])
```

Up here I can add it to my dataframe without any problem `df ['prediction'] = y_pred2`

But I also want to record my multi-class probability at the best value

```
y_pred2 = clf.predict_proba(features2)[0]

array([0.02670249, 0.23888486, 0.00940765, 0.15213608, 0.02719888,
   **0.42038983**, 0.07503347, 0.02960037, 0.02064636])
```

But I also want to record the probability of my multi-class by the best value, but the return from the `predict_proba` function returns an array of all my class, how can I do to record the value of my prediction score.

Example according to my prediction my best class and first position **5** where probability value was **0.42038983**. C

How can I take the best value from my array and write to my dataframe?

Comment: how did your `Y` look like before training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if we deal with the result as a normal list, we can try something like

```
y_pred2 = clf.predict_proba(features2)[0]
someclass = y_pred2.index(max(y_pred2)) # returns the class index *Maximum predicted value
itsprob = max(y_pred2) # returns the Portability *Maximum predicted value
```

then you can either class,prob variable in a df or how ever you like. i cant reproduce your whole scenario as i dont know all of your code